# Java information about process

Tags: java, process, monitor

Suppose I launched new process in JVM using ProcessBuilder.
How can get information about memory used by process and CPU time?

General, problem is this: I have a executable, I need to run it with CPUtime and memory restrictions, I need to set up some callbacks which works on event when CPU or memory restrictions failed. How can I do this in Java?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[OSHI project](https://github.com/oshi/oshi) could help:

> OSHI is a free JNA-based (native) Operating System and Hardware
>   Information library for Java. It doesn't require the installation of
>   any additional native libraries and aims to provide a cross-platform
>   implementation to retrieve system information, such as OS version,
>   processes, memory & CPU usage, disks & partitions, devices, sensors,
>   etc.

The feature you're looking for is:

> Process uptime, cpu, memory usage